# Editing record in delimited file using FileHelper

Tags: c#

I have a simple Delimited log file. I`m using FileHelper library to parse the file using the following code:

```
LogLine record;

FileHelperAsyncEngine<LogLines> engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine<LogLines>();

engine.BeginReadFile(@"C:\logs\Log.log");

while (engine.ReadNext() != null)
{
    record = engine.LastRecord;
    //record.Reported = true; <---I want to be able to edit this!
    // Your Code Here
}
```

Is there any way I can edit this record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will something like this be fine for you?
This will modify second element of that file; could not find method similar to `seek` for that class.

```
 public static void WriteExample()
 {
       FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(SampleType));

       // to Read use:
       SampleType[] res = engine.ReadFile("source.txt") as SampleType[];

       res[1].Field1 = "test";
       res[1].Field2 = 9;

       // to Write use:
       engine.WriteFile("source2.txt", res);
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately what I want to do is to read the record do some action , change it then save it.

Comment: @Stacker: Well you can still do it, you just load all the rows in array (like in above example) - and modify that array as you want-and store back? I could not find other way to do it.

Comment: but this is going to be saving it to a different file if I saved it in the same file it will overwrite it, which means any updates to the file will be lost, what I want to do is to update the exact record without rewriting all the file

Comment: @Stacker: Say you have 10 records in file. This way you can change say only 7th record and leave all records same - then you can output this new array to other file, delete old one maybe and give the new file the name the original file had. If I understood your need correctly.. otherwise maybe someone can post solution which is more suitable for you